# Is there a way to intercept file handling requests in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, file, linux-kernel, gnu

I was wondering if there's a way to *intercept filesystem requests*:
I'm trying to write a logger in C that can log *newly created, modified* and *deleted*  files under Linux.
It would be good if the file entry could be logged in *~realtime*.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The description provided is not very detailed. But have a look at [ionotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) to see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: `I'm trying to write a logger in C that can log newly created, modified and deleted files under Linux` so basically `strace -e open,openat,write,unlink,unlinkat`?

Comment: @kaylum answer looks like the right one to me. I don't know how i didn't find *ionotify* before. Thank you very much! Thank you KamilCuk too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use kernel space for this task. To be more precisely - use VFS. I mean you need to modify all the required filesystem syscalls (open, write, etc) in Linux kernel. Look for `sys_open()` procedure in kernel sources and try to modify it. Then look for other syscalls (read, write, etc).
But if you don't know how to program kernel space - try some user-space solution like [kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum) wrote.

Comment: In modern Linux, `open` is probably just a wrapper for `openat`; that's the system call glibc uses for the C `open()` function.