# How can I intercept failed file openning calls?

Tags: c, linux, file, linux-kernel

Basically, I want to create a program that will monitor whenever another program tries to open a file F, and if that file doesn't exist the program will return a default file (without actually creating a file) the caller program will now proceed as if nothing went wrong.

Not only to read calls but to write calls too. So, lets say the caller used fopen() to open the file F, my program would intercept that and return my default file bytes (without actually creating a file with them), then if the caller tries to write to the file, my program would intercept that and do nothing. The important part is to keep the caller oblivious to the non existance of the file, it should work as if there was a file, even if there isn't. The caller is a generic program, so I don't have control to its inside.

I am thinking about ionotify, as I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63546597/is-there-a-way-to-intercept-file-handling-requests-in-linux)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need this?

Comment: You could always use something like [FUSE](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/filesystems/fuse.html) to make your own "filesystem" that can do this.

Comment: @SafelyFast I don't like how config files fill my directory in some projects simply because their programs only checks if they are in the root. I know it is possible to hide them in most IDEs but I don't like it, I want them to actually be in a different directory. My idea was to make a program that would detect whenever another program searches for its config file my program would "redirect" that to the file in another directory.

Comment: Do you realize how many false positives this would have? Most of them should not be replaced automatically.